# How to run Cucumber tests in parallel at feature or scenario level using cucumber jvm 4.4.0 and without com.github.temyers?

Tags: maven, selenium, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, maven-surefire-plugin

I want to run scenarios/features in parallel, what maven config do i need for this.

Right now i am using com.github.temyers maven dependency but i don't want to use it any further.

- I should be able to run tests in parallel at scenario or feature level.

Comment: Use the built-in parallel execution - https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/parallel-execution/. For scenario level use testng runner or command line. For feature level using junit runner.

Comment: @Grasshopper - i want to have a single runner and a way to change my parallel scheme to feature or scenario instead of having multiple runners.

Comment: There is no option to choose parallel execution mode. Even junit parallel execution is due to some constraint which I am unable to recall. U could google it. Maybe u could try using use maven profile to select the runner to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in parallel execution, as mentioned by @Grasshoper. For more information, see the Cucumber docs on parallel execution.